# Navbar with two rows using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create Navbar for the website with two rows and margin-top: 0 for the top row. This code works but couldn't align the top row with zero margin.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
           icon-image(small icon) slogan(text)

           Site Logo  company name 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code.

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar-inverse nav-upper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-upper">
                        <li>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <span><img src="~/lib/images/icn.png" /></span>
                                 website slogan
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <span><img src="~/lib/images/_image1.png" /></span>
                    Company Name
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.nav-upper ul.navbar-upper li {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like that you want ?

**Bootply** : https://www.bootply.com/N7NZzIDoVm

**Css** :

```
.nav-upper ul.navbar-upper li {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav-upper > div {padding:0;}
```